# On mouseover on the even rows of a table the box shadow is not visible

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem in CSS, I have a `table` and hovering on the `tr` of the table, a CSS is written for the box-shadow.  The problem is this box-shadow is not completely visible for the even row.

[image: image that show hover box shadow on even rows]

The bottom part of box-shadow is hiding because of the next `td` element. Its working fine for odd rows.

Here is the code sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-black-kbwel) of the problem.

I tried with position relative and z-index but that not works for me. Any ideas?

Comment: `tr:nth-child(2n) { background-color: #dddddd;}` this color override the `box-shadow`

Comment: yes @RayeesAC , its overriding the color but I need this color also.

Comment: use `drop-shadow` instead of `box-shadow`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `drop-shadow` instead of `box-shadow`, for example:

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.275rem rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.75));
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<h4>
  Onmouseover on the even row the box shadow is not completely visible
</h4>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Good answer. I like it better than my answer :)

Comment: Thanks, @Peter Darmis this solution is also accepted by my colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative;` on `tr`

```css
table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
      }

      td,
      th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
      }

      tr:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
        
      }
/*change here*/
      tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
    <h2>HTML Table</h2>

    <h4>
      Onmouseover on the even row the box shadow is not completely visible
    </h4>

    <table>
      <tbody><tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Hi @Lalji Tadhani, Thanks for the answer but this answer is not working on chrome its working on firefox.

Comment: @PrabhatKumar Update my answer check now

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

### First Method

> Add `position:relative` to **tr:hover{...}** with `z-index:2`.

> Also add `position:relative` to **tr td{...}** with `z-index:1`.

**That is**

```
tr:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  z-index:2;
}
tr td{
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}
```

**Live DEMO**

```css
tr:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  z-index:2;
}
tr td{
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
      }

      td,
      th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
      }

      tr:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
      }

      tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>HTML Table</h2>

    <h4>
      Onmouseover on the even row the box shadow is not completely visible
    </h4>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Second Method

Use `box-shadow` as **inset**

```
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

```css
tr:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
      }

      td,
      th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
      }

      tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>HTML Table</h2>

    <h4>
      Onmouseover on the even row the box shadow is not completely visible
    </h4>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you want like this @Prabhat Kumar?

Comment: This solution is working only on firefox but not in the chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

remove this style

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
 }
```

if you remove this style it will work

```css
table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
      }

      td,
      th {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
      }

      tr:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
        position: relative;
      }

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
 }
      tr:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>HTML Table</h2>

    <h4>
      Onmouseover on the even row the box shadow is not completely visible
    </h4>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I knew it , this color is overriding the box-shadow but this is in the requirement. I need the alternate color in table rows.